# Clearing the CMOS fixed my computer but I want to know why it was necessary

Tags: boot, cmos

After a shutdown my PC would turn on, but would not boot (nothing appeared on the monitor). I cleared the CMOS on my motherboard via the jumper, and then was able to enter the BIOS setup menu and restore the default settings, and then boot into Windows successfully.

My question is why this was necessary and if it signals an underlying problem I should address?

Thanks

Comment: Were you overclocking anything?

Comment: No, I was/am running everything normally.

Comment: I have seen cmos batteries cause this in rare circumstances, replace the battery with a high quality one.